# How to make dojo textbox cache the previously entered values

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

How can I make dojo textbox dijit to remember previously entered values, like a regular text box (

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this ticket which has a request to enable the autocomplete feature of the dijit textBox.

http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/9562

The creator offers the following workaround, which should work (although, I haven't tried it):

```
dojo.attr(dijit.byId('name').textbox, "autocomplete", "on");
```

However, note in the ticket that this is not enabled by default due to some complexities it can cause with the onChange event. Mainly, that when a value is "autocompleted" in some browsers, it sounds like won't always fire the onChange event properly. The comment is 14 months old, so that may have been fixed in the browser(s) since then, but I don't know whether it has or not. This workaround may fit your needs regardless.

Comment: thanks jason, I'll give it try, so basically if I have textbox has onChange event captured, I should stay away from this workaround then?

Comment: No. Like I said, it's an old comment, it may be fixed in Firefox by now. I'd say play around with it and see how it works for you!